# Does syzygy mean only three aligned bodies, or at least three aligned bodies?

Tags: observational-astronomy, naming

In the precise and rigorous astronomical use of the word, does the term "**syzygy**" refer to an astronomical alignment of three **and only three** bodies? Or, can **syzygy** mean an alignment of three, **or more**, astronomical bodies?

Comment: One thing, please don't use uncommon abbreviations. It took me a while to figuree out what TYIA was. Changed it, if i got it wrong fix it @Plane Wryter

Comment: I've deleted the "Dear Mavens" and "Thank you in advance".  The preferred style is to get down to business quickly,  The Salutation and Sign off are excess to requirements.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, syzygy can be [more than 3](https://www.nytimes.com/1981/03/31/science/science-watch-a-really-big-syzygy.html), but not less than 3.